# How to enable Z-offset on MKS TFT28 V4.0

Tags: marlin, troubleshooting, lcd-screen, mks, print-axis-offset

I am trying to enable Z-offset on MKS MKS TFT28 V4.0 touch screen but I couldn't for some reason.
This is the code that I have uploaded to the Screen firmware in which you can see that I have enabled the babystepping function:

```
#the color of screen background
>cfg_background_color:0x000000

#the color of title text
>cfg_title_color:0xFFFFFF

#the color of temperature,fan,(etc) background
>cfg_state_background_color:0x000000

#the color of temprature,fan,(etc) text
>cfg_state_text_color:0xFFFFFF

#the color of file button
>cfg_filename_background_color:0x494949

#the color of file text
>cfg_filename_color:0xFFFFFF

#the color of background in printing 
>cfg_printingstat_word_background_color:0x000000

#the color of text in printing status
>cfg_printingstat_word_color:0xFFFFFF

#3D effects setting (disable: 0; enable: 1)
>cfg_BUTTON_3D_effects:0

#The screen is flipped 180°(0x00: no flip, 0xEE: flip)
>cfg_OVERTURN_180:0x00

#shield the function of detection power (0:no shield ,1:shield)
>cfg_disable_PWR_det:0

#shield the function of detection filament (0:no shield ,1:shield)
>cfg_disable_MT_det:0

#Whether to support the function of dual extruder single nozzle.(0: disable, 1: enable)
#the extruder number need set to dual.
>cfg_single_nozzle:0

#For the M110 command plus check, the version of Marlin 1.0.2 and below is set to 1, and the other versions are set to 0.
>cfg_M110_add_checkSum:1

#Enable function of display error message. (no:0; Yes:1）
>cfg_display_eeror_message:1

#Enable function of babastep. (no:0; Yes:1）
>cfg_babystep_btn_display:1
```

Thanks